How does lambda capture arguments in perfect forwarding?
I have some difficulty understanding the correctness of lambda capture of arguments with perfect forwarding in the following code:
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<class OS, class ...Args>
void do_work(OS& os, Args&& ...args){
    // Dummy impl; just formats args to os
    (os << ... << std::forward<Args>(args));
}

template<class T>
struct capture_t {T func;};

template<class ...Args>
auto capture(Args&& ...args) {
    return capture_t{ [&] <class OS>(OS & os) { do_work(os, std::forward<Args>(args)...); } };
}

int main()
{
    std::string s{"string"};
    capture(s, "const char*", std::string{"string&&"}, 42).func(std::cout);
    return 0;
}

Q: As we can see, the capture function returns capture_t, which contains a lambda, after which we then call. Does this code have the expected behavior? By expected behavior, I mean that calling the capture should be equivalent to calling do_work directly, that is:
capture(arg1, std::move(arg2), ...).func(os) <===> do_work(os, arg1, std::move(arg2), ...)

Justify your answer using the C++20 standard

Please focus your post on one single question. Asking multiple questions per post is not allowed on Stack Overflow.

Your code doesn't compile.  Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

It compiles now, but it's still incomplete.  What is val?  How is the global do_work related to work_op::do_work?  You should include an example main and some indication of what the behavior of the program should be.

@MilesBudnek After formatting correction, work_op::do_work does not exist.

This terrible abuse of operator overloading makes it hard to see what you're asking. The only thing which could produce a temporary is whatever is returned by arg2(), since args is taking its arguments by reference. Then, that temporary will live till the end of the full subexpression, which could be e.g. os<<work_id<<args(val, arg1, arg2(), ...);, in which case its valid. However auto x = args(val, arg1, arg2(), ...); os << work_id << std::move(x);  is dangling (assuming that arg() returns a temporary)

Is something like this what you want?  Again, it's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve without an example main and some indication of the expected program behavior.

Here's a slightly more complete example that preserves value categories while also being safe in the face of temporary values by storing them internally.

@JaMiT Please look at this question again

@MilesBudnek Please look at this question again

You are not doing perfrect forwarding here. [&] captures all the arguments by reference. args inside the lambda are not the same as args outside - they are all lvalue references, std::forward there is pointless.  If you did capture_t cap = capture(...);  cap.func(std::cout); the program would exhibit undefined behavior by way of accessing temporaries that have already been destroyed; it only works as written because you do everything within one full expression. Demo
